# Customization of apply LinkedIn button

Tags: css, linkedin-api

Has anyone tried to customize this button?
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/apply

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the built-in customization options, please don't change the look-and-feel of this button. It's part of our "Brand".

Comment: Yes, but on some design it looks not so good, also not changable width, height and color not fit to a lot of designs. If you make possible to change w/h and color it will be very-very good and changable border-radius and box-shadow will be awesome=)

Comment: I also need to change this button. Not the look and feel, but the width, height, your buttons stick to top of the line, I need it in middle of it.

Comment: I am sorry to say that "part of your brand" makes your brand incredibly annoying. I've spent already 6 hours of work trying to solve the task of customizing your damn follow button. The only available option right now is to use an OAuth 2.0 authentication system with the user forced to be online in order to refresh the token every 60 days. Just to be able to customize a DAMN FOLLOW BUTTON with a follow counter... Simply incredible.

Answer (score 0):

The Apply With LinkedIn button does have some customizations available.  See this page for more information:
https://developer.linkedin.com/apply-visual-display-options

Comment: I'm meaning more deeply=) via JS and override by CSS, change width, heigh, or apply aplha.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the window to completely load with jQuery, then apply your css overrides. You'd want to hide the button initially and then show it when the css overrides are applied. There might be a bit of a race condition that will show the button without your styling applied at first though.

something like:

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".IN-widget").hide();
});`

$(window).load(function(){
  // change LinkedIn's things you shouldn't change because their branding is important here
  $(".IN-widget").show();
});